# How to efficiently update the state of an application after the user corrects false data about past events?

Tags: design-patterns, reactive-programming

Suppose I'm making a voice-controlled application where spoken utterances will occasionally be misrecognized. I want the user to be able to occasionally correct misrecognized utterances and have the state of application, including the state of the GUI, correct itself as efficiently as possible. Are there existing software frameworks or design patterns that would simplify this? I've looked into self-adjusting computation, but it doesn't seem to be geared towards data that streams in constantly.

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a1080dd9-2a28-46b8-8fce-1dfd556b50ff/how-to-build-your-first-alexa-skill-5-steps-to-get-started

Comment: @bestinamir what does that have to do with this? I'm looking for programming paradigms that would allow me to efficiently recompute the state of an application based on an alteration to the history of user input

Comment: Question sounded too abstract. Another wild idea is unit testing.